# Flutter: Yellow Lines Under Text

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I understand that I do not have a Scaffolding around my text but I'm brand new to flutter and can't seem to work out how to add scaffolding to my text. My code is below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test Bench',
      home: new Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.pinkAccent),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: Text(
            "Hello, World",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 60.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontFamily: 'Oswald',
                color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check by following code. Also refer

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test Bench',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: new Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.pinkAccent),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
            child: Text(
              "Hello, World",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 60.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontFamily: 'Oswald',
                  color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a explanation for this:

Always uses Scaffold (generally better) or any other component that provides material theme like a simple Material widget

[remove yellow line text](https://flutteragency.com/how-to-remove-yellow-lines-under-text-widgets-in-flutter/)

Answer (score 0):

We can remove yellow lines by adding the Parent widget as "Material" or use "Scaffold"

```
return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Text('Test')),
        ),
      ),
    );
```